# Call Recording in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

- Can you route me to API's capable of intercepting incoming and outgoing phone calls in Windows Phone 8 and record the call conversation ?
- Once Recording is in progress, is there a way to simultaneously packetize these data and send it over to a remote server ?
- Finally can I set this call recording application to be auto invoked whenever there is an incoming & outgoing Call ?
- Since SIP is not exposed in Windows Phone 8 do we have an alternate approach to serve the purpose (say a 3rd party Library) ?

Comment: I would also like to know how can we record calls on WP8. Also, what does Call recorder pro use to record phone calls?

Comment: It is a very sought after functionality that seems to be missing from just about every mobile OS these days. Why aren't they letting us develop recording apps anymore?

Comment: Because users don't want shitty spyware applications recording everything they're doing unintentionally.

Comment: @STT As Claus Jørgensen said, it is not possible with the API's to record calls. If you try Call Recorder Pro you will quickly notice that the app just seems to record the sound from the speaker using the microphone, so all sound around you will also be recorded.

Answer (score 12):

> Can you route me to API's capable of intercepting incoming and outgoing phone calls in Windows Phone 8 and record the call conversation ?

No, there is no way to intercept anything on Windows Phone. (And this makes the rest of your questions invalid).

Comment: Kind of too short answer. What if not intercepting the incoming call automatically but the user starts the recording manually, is it possible to record the call audio?

Comment: No 3rd party applications can intercept anything related to calling, this includes the sound. Only if you made your own VoIP client, could you do it.

Comment: This is the same as in Android, the US law forbids recording calls, so the hardware manufactors distribute their firmware without any support for it.

Comment: We can implement call interception / recording in Android Platform. Legal compliance is a question mark though

Comment: @stdcall, that is not correct.

US law does NOT forbid recording calls.  It is illegal under federal law to record a telephone conversation when NO ONE who is a part of the conversation knows it is being recorded (thus, if one of the people involved in the conversation was recording it, that is legal under federal law).  Some US states, not all, have laws forbidding recording when ALL parties to a call do not know it is being recorded.  But even then, if the parties are notified it is NOT illegal and your right to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to interact which can identify the incoming call,
Example : New Version of **TrueCaller** application, it will integrate its app with **Network+** app of system and then it will possible but its special api that Microsoft (not Nokia) provided to them I try to contact them since last 2 months i will I have good news/ bad news in very short period of time.

Thanks.