# OpenNETCF.Media.WaveAudio dll for windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dll, windows-phone-8

I want this OpenNETCF.Media.WaveAudio dll for call recording in Windows phone app. I also search on google but can't find except below link. It show that using this dll you can add this feature in your app but there is no download link in this page and also on google there is no download link.

http://www.opennetcf.com/library/sdf/html/b8f79788-d32c-2b7d-ce25-349f1d616259.htm

If some one have solution for call recoding in windows phone then please suggest me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OpenNETCF.Media.WaveAudio` is a namespace, not an assembly.  The namespace is in the `OpenNETCF.dll` assembly, which is part of the [Smart Device Framework, which is downloadable here](http://www.opennetcf.com/Products/SmartDeviceFramework.aspx).

That said, there are two problems:

1. It's for Windows CE and older Windows Mobile devices.  It won't work with Windows Phone  (becasue it P/Invokes to get device access, which you can't do in WinPhone).
2. It's allows you to record WAV audio from an audio source like the microphone (provided you meet the OS requirements of #1) but it's not going to allow you to record a call.

Really you should be asking a question along the lines of "How do I record call audio?" with a `windows-phone` tag.  [That has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374223/call-recording-in-windows-phone-8).